# Можно ли перебирать строки в stdout_lines без указания конкретной строки в ansible

Tags: bash, ansible, yaml

Я написал плейбук который сохранял в переменную названия таблиц в базе данных. Теперь мне нужно сопоставить каждую! строку с grep. Т.е. если grep нашел файл который подходит под название то он отправлял его в базу данных (для восстановления). Саму процедуру отправки в базу данных я понимаю как сделать. Сама суть что я хочу сделать: чтобы задача Compare tables and dumps выполнялась для каждого значения в переменной. Можно ли как-нибудь сделать чтобы stdout_lines прогонялась не для конкретно 0 или 1 элемента а для каждого. Что то вроде цикла for на манер ansible

```
- name: Getting tables into clickhouse
  shell:
    cmd: 'docker exec -i clickhouse clickhouse-client -d default --query "SHOW TABLES;"'
  register: tables

- debug:
    var: tables.stdout_lines

- name: Compare tables and dumps
  shell:
    cmd: "ls /data/data/backups/clickhouse/ | grep -E {{ tables.stdout_lines[0] }} "
  register: output

- debug:
    var: output.stdout_lines
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1237688/191416 не оно?